# MVCContrib pager images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I am able to use the MVCContrib Grid Pager as in the following sample

```
Html.Pager(Model.CustomerList)
        .First("First")
        .Last("Last")
        .Next("Next")
        .Previous("Previous")
```

Is there any way to modify the links to show clickable images instead of plain text?

**EDIT**

I have applied Darin solution and it works very nice except for the image not being showed by the browser. This is the markup generated by the pager helper

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="paginationLeft">1-2 di 4</span>
    <span class="paginationRight">
        <span class="first"></span> | 
        <span class="previous"></span> | 
        <a href="/x/Hearing/HomeSummary?page=2">
            <span class="next"></span>
        </a> | 
        <a href="/x/Hearing/HomeSummary?page=2">
            <span class="last"></span>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

and these are the CSS rules defined

```
.pagination span.paginationRight span.first { width: 12px; height: 12px; background-image: url('../images/disabled-pager-first.png') }
.pagination span.paginationRight span.next { width: 12px; height: 12px; background-image: url('../images/disabled-pager-next.png') }
.pagination span.paginationRight span.last { width: 12px; height: 12px; background-image: url('../images/disabled-pager-last.png') }
.pagination span.paginationRight span.previous { width: 12px; height: 12px; background-image: url('../images/disabled-pager-previous.png') }

.pagination span.paginationRight a span.first { width: 12px; height: 12px; background-image: url('../images/pager-first.png') }
.pagination span.paginationRight a span.next { width: 12px; height: 12px; background-image: url('../images/pager-next.png') }
.pagination span.paginationRight a span.last { width: 12px; height: 12px; background-image: url('../images/pager-last.png') }
.pagination span.paginationRight a span.previous { width: 12px; height: 12px; background-image: url('../images/pager-previous.png') }
```

As you can see from the following images the correct CSS rules match the markup generated. Still I can't see images on the browser. Any idea?

For disabled images
[image]

For enabled images
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course:

```
<%= Html.Pager(Model.CustomerList)
        .First("<img src=\"http://example.com/first.png\" alt=\"first\" />")
        .Last("<img src=\"http://example.com/last.png\" alt=\"last\" />")
        .Next("<img src=\"http://example.com/next.png\" alt=\"next\" />")
        .Previous("<img src=\"http://example.com/previous.png\" alt=\"previous\" />")
%>
```

or if you prefer to use CSS:

```
<%= Html.Pager(Model.CustomerList)
        .First("<span class=\"first\" />")
        .Last("<span class=\"last\" />")
        .Next("<span class=\"next\" />")
        .Previous("<span class=\"previous\" />")
%>
```

and then in a separate CSS file define the background images.

---

UPDATE:

For background images to be applied your span elements need to have some content. So try adding a space:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="paginationLeft">1-2 di 4</span>
    <span class="paginationRight">
        <span class="first">&nbsp;</span> | 
        <span class="previous">&nbsp;</span> | 
        <a href="/x/Hearing/HomeSummary?page=2">
            <span class="next">&nbsp;</span>
        </a> | 
        <a href="/x/Hearing/HomeSummary?page=2">
            <span class="last">&nbsp;</span>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion works pretty good. However there's a problem if I am on the first, or in the last, page. I would like the pager could use a dimmed image for the links that are inactive. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: @Lorenzo, clickable pages will be inside an anchor tag. So you could write a different CSS rule for those spans that are inside an anchor: `.pagination a span { /** ENABLE IMAGE HERE **/ }`. By default you could dim images and enable those that respect this CSS rule: `.pagination span { /** DISABLE IMAGE HERE **/ }`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am going to try it :)

Comment: @Darin: I've ended up with these css rules: for disabled images `.pagination span.paginationRight span.first { width: 12px; height: 12px; background-image: url('../images/disabled-pager-first.png') }` and for enabled images `.pagination span.paginationRight a span.first { width: 12px; height: 12px; background-image: url('../images/pager-first.png') }`. With Chrome DT I am able to see the correct classes applied to markup but I dont see the images. Any hint?

Comment: @Lorenzo, could you try inspecting with FireBug? It shows what CSS rules are applied to each DOM element and you could see whether the correct images are applied and if the path is OK or not.

Comment: @Darin: I did it already. I can see that the correct classes are applied in the `Matched CSS Rules` section (I am using Chrome Developer Tool). Paths are correct and the image exists. mmmmh...

Comment: @Darin: I have edited my question to add further details on this problem. Could you please have a look at it? Thanks

Comment: @Lorenzon, I think it is a problem with how empty spans are interpreted. Try adding a space content: `<span class="first">&nbsp;</span>`

Comment: It worked great adding `display: inline-block;` to the CSS. thanks again for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

Try rolling your own.  I've implemented a custom Grid and Pager that takes advantage of jQuery UI themes - it may help you roll your own or you could use the implementation.  Blog is [here](http://tdryan.blogspot.com/2011/01/themed-ajaxified-mvccontrib-grid-with.html) with links to a demo and source.

Comment: congratulation! it looks impressive :)